# How to summarize all records in Crystal Reports 8.01

Tags: sql-server, vb6, crystal-reports

I have a problem with how to sum all records in Crystal Reports 8.01. I'm using VB6.

```
example:
date             tools               in              out              
1/19/2012       stone               100              0
1/20/2012       stone                50              0
1/21/2012       stone                30              0
1/25/2012       stone                 0              40
1/26/2012       stone                 0              20

total in  until now : 180
total out until now :  60
```

I use the following code in VB 6:

```vb
With CrystalReport1
 .SelectionFormula = "{stock.dates} >= #" & Format(DTPicker5.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#        and {stock.dates}<= #" & Format(DTPicker6.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"

End With
```

In Crystal Reports, use formula editor:

```
Sum ({stock.in}) ==> for total in
Sum ({stock.out}) ==> for total out
```

When i run date 1/19/2012 until 1/26/2012 the result is:

```
total in until  now : 180
total out until now :  60 its true
```

But when I run date 1/20/2012 until 1/26/2012 the result is:

```
 total in  until now : 80 (the value is change)
 total out until now : 60
```

How do I make the value of the sum not change from the beginning until the last date when chosen date?

Comment: I tried hard, but this question still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Probably he needs total of all records, but display only some last records.

Comment: yea, i needs total of all records but display only one

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

1. Create some stored procedure, able to compute total balance for any date and use that procedure in report
2. Do not filter records based on date (ie not set selectionformula), but supress displaying old records; you need to use some prameter to forward this date to crystal object (slow, but sometimes only possibility)