# How To Sum all Records in  crystal-reports-8-01

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

*Example:*

```
date           |   value               
------------------------------
1/19/2012      |    100              
1/20/2012      |    50              
1/21/2012      |    30              
1/25/2012      |    0              
1/26/2012      |    0
```

total **GRAND TOTAL** until now : **180**

In Crystal Reports, using formula editor:

```
Sum ({stock.in}) ==> for total in
```

When I run date **1/19/2012** until **1/26/2012** the result is:

total **GRAND TOTAL** until  now : **180** (TRUE)

But when I run date **1/20/2012** until **1/26/2012** the result is:

total **GRAND TOTAL** until now : **80** (the value is changed)
grand total from begining until now must be 180

How do I make the value of the sum not changed from the beginning until the last date when chosen date? I need them for grand total.

Comment: WAS YOUR CAPS LOCK key stuck?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to summarize all records in Crystal Reports 8.01](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060782/how-to-summarize-all-records-in-crystal-reports-8-01)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total for all records, while only displaying some of them, the answer is to remove the selection condition, and instead conditionally suppress the detail section where the records fall outside the selection range.